# TensorFlow fails to compile

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

Getting the following errors which trying to compile TensorFlow from source.
Any thoughts would be helpful.

```
bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_Cgen_Unn_Uops_Upy_Uwrappers_Ucc___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasGemmEx@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_Cgen_Unn_Uops_Upy_Uwrappers_Ucc___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasZhpmv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_Cgen_Unn_Uops_Upy_Uwrappers_Ucc___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cufftExecD2Z@libcufft.so.9.0'
bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_Cgen_Unn_Uops_Upy_Uwrappers_Ucc___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasSrotg_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_Cgen_Unn_Uops_Upy_Uwrappers_Ucc___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cufftExecR2C@libcufft.so.9.0'
bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_Cgen_Unn_Uops_Upy_Uwrappers_Ucc___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasSsyrk_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_Cgen_Unn_Uops_Upy_Uwrappers_Ucc___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDgemm_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_Cgen_Unn_Uops_Upy_Uwrappers_Ucc___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cufftSetWorkArea@libcufft.so.9.0'
bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_Cgen_Unn_Uops_Upy_Uwrappers_Ucc___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasChemm_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_Cgen_Unn_Uops_Upy_Uwrappers_Ucc___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasZher2k_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_Cgen_Unn_Uops_Upy_Uwrappers_Ucc___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cufftExecC2C@libcufft.so.9.0'
bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_Cgen_Unn_Uops_Upy_Uwrappers_Ucc___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `curandSetStream@libcurand.so.9.0'
bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_Cgen_Unn_Uops_Upy_Uwrappers_Ucc___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDrotm_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Spython_Cgen_Unn_Uops_Upy_Uwrappers_Ucc___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed@libcurand.so.9.0'
```

Answer (score 22):

There seems to be a bug in our build. I was able to reproduce the same on my machine. Looks like the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` does not always get properly propagated during bazel build. In my case, I was able to successfully build when I used this command:

```
bazel build  --config=opt --config=cuda tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package --action_env="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

Comment: IMO it's a problem either with bazel or with TF BUILD files. For some reason bazel does not pass -L <library location> when it attempts to link the library that depends on other shared libraries. Relying on LD_LIBRARY_PATH (which is intended for *runtime* linker's use) to compile-time linker so it can find the dependencies is just covering up the issue. If a user specified external library as the dependency, the build system should provide all necessary flags to successfully link with such library.

Comment: This did not work for me with cuda 9.0, cudnn 9.1 and tensorflow r1.8 with git cherry-pick e489b60

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error just yesterday while trying to build tensorflow from source against an apparently valid cuda 9.0. In my case, no combinations of `git clean` and `action_env` helped - `ld` via bazel would consistently refuse to acknowledge the cuda libs.

I ended up following the instructions in [this thread](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/845363/libcublas-so-7-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file/): As root, create a file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda.conf` with the one line

```
/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

(Assuming your `/usr/local/cuda/` is linked to your concrete cuda directory, e.g., `/usr/local/cuda-9.0/`.)

Then issue `sudo ldconfig`.
With that, the build ran through, and tensorflow is using my GPU.

Answer (score 0):

In an attempt to make this problem easier to search for: The error message I got also included at the top:

`libcublas.so.9.0, needed by bazel-out/[...]/libtensorflow_framework.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)`

and so on for libcudnn etc.

When I encountered this problem, I first added `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` and `/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64` to my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and tried to rebuild (without `--action_env`).  Didn't work.

I then did a clean reconfigure and build, again without `--action_env`, and it worked.  I cleaned my repository by way of `git clean -xdf`, which, caution, will nuke all files in your repository that are not known to git.  :)

Maybe `--action_env` would have obviated the need to do a clean rebuild, I dunno.  But if the libraries were in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before doing the very first build, I expect that you wouldn't need `--action_env`.

Answer (score 0):

I appended `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` AFTER the errors occurred. It didn't work. Then I modified `.tf_configure.bazelrc` with `build --action_env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=..."` again. Re-compile the project and pass!