# Building tensor flow from source using bazel on Ubuntu 16.04. Error is ---> Linking of rule '//tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco' failed (Exit 1)

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, bazel, tensorflow

I am just trying to use my gpu with tensorflow on a Ubuntu 16.04 64bit system. I noticed while running some tensorflow commands that neither my cpu nor my gpu were using all of the configurations available. Thus, I updated the driver for my Nvidia GTX-970 card to x86_64-384.98, updated the toolkit to 9.0, and the cuDNN to 7.0.

I have verified the installation and can write some simple code using python to wrap Cuda language to access the GPU for simple pings of info and short calculations. Yet, I cannot access the GPU from tensorflow code. This should not be the focus, but simply the impetus for trying to update everything.

I proceeded to install tensorflow from source following the instructions at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#ConfigureInstallation

My configuration options have been everything and in between. I do choose to use python3, I am choosing cuda. The tensorflow configure settings are as follows

```
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /usr/bin/python]: /usr/bin/python3
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
jemalloc as malloc support will be enabled for TensorFlow.
No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow.
No Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow.
No Amazon S3 File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow.
No XLA JIT support will be enabled for TensorFlow.
No GDR support will be enabled for TensorFlow.
No VERBS support will be enabled for TensorFlow.
No OpenCL SYCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow.
CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow.
Please specify the CUDA SDK version you want to use: 9.0
Please specify the location where CUDA 9.0 toolkit is installed.: /usr/local/cuda
Please specify the cuDNN version you want to use.: 7.0
Please specify the location where cuDNN 7.0 library is installed.: /usr/local/cuda/lib64
Please specify a list of comma-separated Cuda compute capabilities you want to build with.: 5.2
Do you want to use clang as CUDA compiler? [y/N]: N
```

Note that my most recent attempt was to install Clang and try to compile with that instead of gcc. I also tried using gcc-4.8 in addition to the default 5.4 currently installed on my system. It made no difference. I still get the following error(s) after executing the bazel command;

```
ERROR: /home/--homedir--/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/BUILD:330:1: Linking of rule '//tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco' failed (Exit 1): crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/--homedir--/.cache/bazel/_bazel_--homedir--/64ee7f1f669c952ba6e88c08d7965da3/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH=/usr/local/cuda \
    CUDNN_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64 \
    GCC_HOST_COMPILER_PATH=/usr/bin/gcc-4.8 \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
    PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python3 \
    PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages \
    TF_CUDA_CLANG=0 \
    TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES=5.2 \
    TF_CUDA_VERSION=9.0 \
    TF_CUDNN_VERSION=7 \
    TF_NEED_CUDA=1 \
    TF_NEED_OPENCL_SYCL=0 \
  external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/clang/bin/crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc -o bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco '-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../../../../_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow' '-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../../../../_solib_local/_U@local_Uconfig_Ucuda_S_Scuda_Ccudart___Uexternal_Slocal_Uconfig_Ucuda_Scuda_Scuda_Slib' '-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../../../../_solib_local/_U_S_Sthird_Uparty_Smkl_Cintel_Ubinary_Ublob___Uexternal_Smkl_Slib' -Lbazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow -Lbazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U@local_Uconfig_Ucuda_S_Scuda_Ccudart___Uexternal_Slocal_Uconfig_Ucuda_Scuda_Scuda_Slib -Lbazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Sthird_Uparty_Smkl_Cintel_Ubinary_Ublob___Uexternal_Smkl_Slib '-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/,-rpath,$ORIGIN/..,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../..,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../../..' -pthread -Wl,-rpath,../local_config_cuda/cuda/lib64 -Wl,-rpath,../local_config_cuda/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64 -Wl,-no-as-needed -B/usr/bin/ -pie -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -no-canonical-prefixes -pass-exit-codes '-Wl,--build-id=md5' '-Wl,--hash-style=gnu' -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,@bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco-2.params)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcublas.so.9.0, needed by bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcufft.so.9.0, needed by bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcurand.so.9.0, needed by bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasGemmEx@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasZhpmv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cufftExecD2Z@libcufft.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasSrotg_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cufftExecR2C@libcufft.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasSsyrk_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDgemm_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cufftSetWorkArea@libcufft.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasChemm_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasZher2k_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cufftExecC2C@libcufft.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `curandSetStream@libcurand.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDrotm_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed@libcurand.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cufftExecZ2D@libcufft.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasStpsv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasSspmv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDznrm2_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasCtrsv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasZdscal_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasIzamax_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasCgeru_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasZhpr2_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasZher2_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `curandDestroyGenerator@libcurand.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasStpmv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasIsamax_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cufftMakePlan1d@libcufft.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasSsbmv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasSgemm_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasScopy_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasScnrm2_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cufftMakePlan3d@libcufft.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasSnrm2_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDtbmv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasSgemmEx@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasZtpsv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDrotg_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasSetStream_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasSswap_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasZtrsv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasSrotmg_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasIsamin_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDspmv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cufftSetStream@libcufft.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasCrotg_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasCher_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasSdot_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasCsscal_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDtpmv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasStrsm_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDsyr_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasSsyr2_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasCsyr2k_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDrot_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasSaxpy_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `curandGenerateUniformDouble@libcurand.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `curandGenerateUniform@libcurand.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDgbmv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasSsyr2k_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDnrm2_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasZtrsm_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasStrmm_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasZgeru_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDdot_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasCher2_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cufftSetAutoAllocation@libcufft.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasSgemv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDsbmv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasIdamin_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasCgemv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasCtrsm_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDtrmm_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasChpmv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasCdotu_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasZherk_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasZtpmv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasCgerc_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cufftDestroy@libcufft.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasZhemm_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cufftCreate@libcufft.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasZgemv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasCaxpy_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasChpr2_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDtrmv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasIdamax_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasZtrmv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cufftPlan3d@libcufft.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDtbsv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasZhemv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasZhbmv_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
bazel-out/local_linux-py3-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined reference to `cublasDsyrk_v2@libcublas.so.9.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 673.255s, Critical Path: 21.40s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I deleted about 30% of the undefined reference as they were mostly similar in the few files that are sought.

fyi - Build label: 0.7.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a link to the path ended up solving the problem. The problem is identical to this persons (poorly tagged and described) question, and is solved by this person's answer ---> https://stackoverflow.com/a/47295278/4838973

Although identical, I would suggest not marking this as such until the linked question is better tagged for the search engines to find.